# Getting unicode decode error in python?

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, unicode

I am using facebook graph API but getting error when I try to run graph.py
How should I resolve this problem of charmap. I am facing unicode decode error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K98jb.png)

In graph.py :

```
table = json2html.convert(json = variable)

     htmlfile=table.encode('utf-8')

     f = open('Table.html','wb')
     f.write(htmlfile)
     f.close()

    #   replacing '&gt'  with '>' and  '&lt' with '<'
     f = open('Table.html','r')
     s=f.read()
     s=s.replace("&gt;",">")
     s=s.replace("&lt;","<")
     f.close()

    #    writting content to html file
     f = open('Table.html','w')
     f.write(s)
     f.close()

     #  output
     webbrowser.open("Table.html")
else:
print("We couldn't find anything for",PageName)
```

I could not understand why I am facing this issue. Also getting some error with 's=f.read()'

Comment: always send error as text.

Comment: you may have to open with correct encoding - ie. `latin-1` - `open(..., encode="latin-1")` Use Google to check in what encoding is char `0x8d`

Comment: @furas What edit should I make in my code

Comment: BTW: you could replace in `htmlfile` and save it and then you don't need to open it again.

Comment: @furas So I need to edit my html file right.

Comment: yes, you can change it in `htmlfile` and save it. In error message I see it tries to guess encoding in file when you read it and finally it uses encoding `cp1250` to read it (probably because Windows use `cp1250` as default in system). So next time use `open( ..., encoding='utf-8')` so it will not guessing.

Comment: @furas So I should only change this line  `webbrowser.open("Table.html")` to  `webbrowser.open("Table.html",encoding='utf-8')` am I correct nothing to change anything more.

Comment: not `webbrowser.open()` but `f = open( , "r", encoding=...)`

Comment: @furas Only that one line I have to changed nothing else am I right ?

Comment: first try it and see if you get error, and later ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In error message I see it tries to guess encoding used in file when you read it and finally it uses encoding `cp1250` to read it (probably because Windows use `cp1250` as default in system) but it is incorrect encoding becuse you saved it as `'utf-8'`.

So you have to use `open( ..., encoding='utf-8')` and it will not have to guess encoding.

```
 # replacing '&gt'  with '>' and  '&lt' with '<'
 f = open('Table.html','r', encoding='utf-8')
 s = f.read()
 f.close()

 s = s.replace("&gt;",">")
 s = s.replace("&lt;","<")

 # writting content to html file
 f = open('Table.html','w', encoding='utf-8')
 f.write(s)
 f.close()
```

But you could change it before you save it. And then you don't have to open it again.

```
table = json2html.convert(json=variable)


table = table.replace("&gt;",">").replace("&lt;","<")


f = open('Table.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(table)
f.close()

#  output
webbrowser.open("Table.html")
```

---

BTW: python has function [html.unescape(text)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) to replace all "chars" like `&gt;` (so called [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references))

```
import html

table = json2html.convert(json=variable)


table = html.unescape(table)


f = open('Table.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(table)
f.close()

#  output
webbrowser.open("Table.html")
```